# Fuzzily recognise characters in an image

Tags: image-processing

I'm looking for a suitable algorithm that can recognise that an image that slightly differs from a known image of a letter matches.

That is, I know that the following images are the letters s, t, e, and v.

[image]

How would I go about detecting that another image of the letter s in a similar typeface (font family, size, and weight) is the same letter?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that algorithms which are being used in OCR will be suitable here. [This](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) is an example of an OCR which use the [k-nearest neighbor algorithm](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) which is a method for classifying objects based on closest training example.